# Disable download option for google drive file by python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, centos7

Is there an option to disable a file download option over python API. I have looked for the different option under the API URL, But have not found any option.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list

But google drive web UI have an option to disable a file download.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a permission like the others, because it applies to all users equally. Rather, this checkbox corresponds to the `labels.restricted` field of the [File object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) in question:

> `labels.restricted`   `boolean`   Whether viewers and commenters are prevented from downloading, printing, and copying this file.

Answer (score 1):

To disable copy, print, or download permission for readers and commenters we can use Update functionality of Drive API v3 and set **copyRequiresWriterPermission** to **true**.

Python code to do this.

```
metafile = {
'copyRequiresWriterPermission' : "true",
}

service.files().update(fileId="Enter File ID", supportsAllDrives=True,body = metafile).execute()
```

Set **supportsAllDrives**=**True** if your file is in shared drive.

If you are confused by **service** refer https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python